# Foreign key same as associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

i have a cutom foreign key name (non association+_id) like so:

```
belongs_to :investment_advisor, :foreign_key => "investment_advisor"
```

This creates a problem because rails gets confused and doesnt know if im referring to the association or the foreign key. Is there any way i can rename the foreign key *(without touching the database)* to something else? Like a variable or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rename your association, for one:

```
belongs_to :investment_advisor_obj, 
           :foreign_key => "investment_advisor", 
           :class_name => "InvestmentAdvisor"
```

(or you could pick a less silly name)

Comment: But doesnt `:investment_advisor` need to be the name of the table? Or is it just the name of the table, and the `:class_name` is the  name of the table

Comment: @JonahKatz: no, it needs not. But Rails has to be able to find the other class in this association. Hence the `:class_name` option.

Comment: give it a go @JonahKatz. The name of the association is really just that, a name. It finds out the table name just by asking `InvestmentAdvisor.table_name`

Comment: @sergio Oh perfect! I think that working. But if i call `contact.investment_advisor`, i just get the `investment_advisor`'s id. How wold i call a column in investment_advisor called, say, `parent`?

Comment: @JonahKatz: if you go with my code, use `contact.investment_advisor` to get the id, and `contact.investment_advisor_obj` to get the actual advisor object.

Comment: @Sergio Wonderful. I was looking all over for some good info on this stuff, do you have a source where you can get all conventions and methods and what not? Or just the API?

Comment: @JonahKatz: use excellent [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). :-)